# Possible chlorophenol issue?

Tags: off-flavor

I recently brewed a pale ale, 100% 2 row, ~13*P, hopped to about 40IBU with Azacca, and fermented with Voss Kveik at around 30*c. I ended up with an awful hose water flavour, which I can only assume is chlorophenols.

I have had this flavour only once before, about 5 years ago, on a different brewing rig, with entirely different ingredients. I'm confident in my sanitation, and as I haven't had this issue before with this setup, I'm confident in my water, as well as my process.

In addition, I also made a stout the same day, immediately after the pale, and it shows no sign of this flaw. To make matters even murkier, the flavour seems to have diminished greatly after about 3 weeks in a keg.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to what might have happened?

Comment: What is your water source?  If its municipal/town water supply the levels or chlorine or chloramine can sometimes spike due to water quality or maintenance issues "upstream" of you.

Comment: As I mentioned, I haven't had this issue for many years, and brewed another beer on the same day, ie with the same water, with no issues. It is municipal water, but as far as I'm aware my city doesn't use chloramine, and the water for this beer had sat overnight, so should have been prettu good on the chlorine front. The other beer should have been worse.

Comment: I don't think the Chlorophenols would come from any other source than water.  But the second beer being clean is interesting.  Did you use the Kveik strain on the stout too?

Comment: I haven't brewed with Kveik yet.  But I've had a handful of commercial beers with it. What was the source of your Voss Kveik?

Comment: That was my thinking as well, I so haven't heard of chlorophenols diminishing. The stout wasn't with the kveik, it was with an English strain (don't recall off the top of my head). I'm sort of wondering if this is something that seems like, but isn't, chlorophenols.

Comment: I think it might be the Kveik.  I've experienced weird flavors from it that possible I could misconstrued as chlorine issues.  Possibly  I could accept that's also why it's fading a bit with time.  The other thing too depending on the source of the Kveik; other than a reputable commercial source, homebrewers are doing weird things to culture Kveik at home that inevitably leads to contaminated cultures.  That could be giving the odd phenol flavor that one might assume is chlorophenols too.  Just thoughts and spitballing with you.

Comment: I had brewed another similar beer with the kveik before, with no issue. This was repitched from that one. The initial pitch was from a yeast bay vial (I think, it was a proper lab anyway). This would have been its second beer. You've raised some good points. When I did the first brew with the Voss, I pitched half the vial into the first beer, then put the rest in a starter to grow for later use. The problem beer was repitched from the first beer. I'll try another similar beer, but use kveik from the starter, which should be cleaner in every way.

Comment: It's possible that they were repairing/replacing a pump or instrument and disinfected it prior to bolting it in, introducing a small increase of contaminants (enough to taste the difference). You can test the waters before using them: https://www.morebeer.com/articles/removing_chloramines_from_water - is it worth buying a few jugs of bottled water to get the purest tasting water ...

Comment: That's possible, yeah. I'll look into it, ta

Comment: I’ve had some pretty funky results with Azacca alone. Similar to what is can be described as chlorophenolic. I’d go through my notes and make sure you didn’t use too much Azacca. It might be there pairing of the Azacca with Kveik that met be perceived as off in flavor. I personally never use Azacca

Comment: As the only hop addition anymore..

Comment: A few thoughts. Rubber hose is usually chlorine issues. You stated that the yeast was re-pitched from a batch which used a half vial of the yeast. It could be that the yeast that were re-pitched were stressed out from the previous batch. A few factors could lead to this, if the first batch was large in total sugar (lots of work for the yeast to do), if the yeast cake was left for a prolonged period following fermentation (reduced glycogen stores to support them), insufficient aeration (inadequate cell health during replication). That it wasn't observed on second batch is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Chlorophenols do not diminish, therefore you have some other contamination issue.

I would always treat my water from the tap with Metabisulphite to knock out any chlorine just to be sure, as presence of chlorophenols is grim, and unrecoverable.

My first guess would always be sanitation, I have been doing this years and every so often something will slip through the net. Now that I have PAA this is much rarer.